# How to locally test set Cookies with the Same Origine Policy

Tags: javascript, node.js, reactjs, express

I have a problem when testing my web app locally.
I set cookies in a request response (here is how) :

```
const token = createToken(user._id);
res.cookie("jwt", token, { httpOnly: true, maxAge: maxAge,  });
res.status(201).json({ user: user._id });
return res;
```

But I encounter an error about Same domain Policy when executing the following request in the React Client:

```
axios.post(`${process.env.REACT_APP_API_URL}api/user/login`, {
                email: email,
                password: password,
            },
            {
                withCredentials: true
            })
            .then((res) => {
                if (res.data.errors) {
                    //Show errors
                }
            })
            .catch((err) => {
                console.log(err);
            });
```

I tried to execute it with the parameter withCredentials : false

The request works but the cookie is not stored
But I have set-Cookie in the response of my request

And this is my CORS options :

```
const corsOptions = {
    origin: process.env.CLIENT_URL,
    credentials: true,
    allowedHeaders: ["sessionId", "Content-Type"],
    exposedHeaders: ["sessionId"],
    methods: "GET,HEAD,PUT,PATCH,POST,DELETE",
    preflightContinue: false
};
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I remplace my cors options by :

```
const corsOptions = {origin: process.env.CLIENT_URL,credentials: true};
```

and add :

```
app.options('*', cors(corsOptions));
```

and now it's working